# Matlab continue graph for second loop

Tags: matlab, graph, simulation

```
    %free fall of a ball
clc
clear all
close all

v0=5; % initial velocity up
g=9.8; %free fall acceleration
v1=(0.7/0.9)*v0


% time of fly
tup=v0/9;

nsteps=10; %number of frames
dt=tup/nsteps; %time step
Hmax=v0*tup+(-g)*tup*tup/2; % maximum altitude

altitude(1:nsteps+1)=0; %define array for position Y
time=0:dt:tup;% define time array

%initilaise plot
figure(1)
axis([0,2*tup,0,2*Hmax]);
hold on

% loop
for i=1:nsteps
    altitude(i)=v0*time(i)+(-g)*time(i)*time(i);
    plot(time(i),altitude(i), 'ro')
    grid on;
    M(i)=getframe;
end

%loop bouncing
for i=1:nsteps
    altitude(i)=v1*time(i)+(-g)*time(i)*time(i);
    plot(time(i),altitude(i), 'ro')
    grid on;
    M(i)=getframe; 

end


%make movie
movie(M);
movie2avi(M, 'C:\Users\Mehmet\Desktop\avi\mm','compression','none');

%extra plots
figure(2)
plot(time(1:nsteps),altitude(1:nsteps))

figure(3)
plot(time(1:nsteps),altitude(1:nsteps),'ro')
```

We have this ball bouncing simulation. What we want to do is, to continue loop 2 after loop 1 in graph.So, it will be continious bouncing simulation.2 bouncings are shown from 1:10 steps but we want second loop to be shown after 10 steps.

Comment: Your second loop overwrites all the variables of the first loop.

Comment: we already know that it overwrites. we just keep it this way to check does our program work properly. thats why we are asking how to make 2nd loop to be continious of 1st loop in graph. And to show both loops in one graph as once again continous of 1st loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches, depending upon what effect you're going for.  The simplest is to simply add `hold on` as a separate command after each of your plot commands.  This will keep accumulating new lines/dots without erasing the old ones.  To stop this effect, add a `hold off` command.  The next `plot` command will then erase everything and plot on a clean graph.

Alternatively, if you only want to show a fixed number of the previous steps (and not *all* of them, as the `hold on` will do), you'll have to explicitly hold onto the previous values.  Something like this:

```
% loop
max_history = 10;  %plot this many symbols
for i=1:nsteps
    altitude(i)=v0*time(i)+(-g)*time(i)*time(i);

    %get the historical and current data points to plot
    start_ind = i-max_history+1;  %here's the oldest point that you'd like
    start_ind = max([start_ind, 1]) %but you can't plot negative indices
    inds = [start_ind:i];  %here are the ones to plot

    %update the plot
    plot(time(inds),altitude(inds), 'ro');
    grid on;
    %you might need a "drawnow" here
    M(i)=getframe;
end
```

Copy this same idea into your other `for` loops and you should be good-to-go!